# Get indices of numpy array where values are offset from themselves by some amount

Tags: numpy

If I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9])
n = 3
```

How can I, without the use of loops, find the indices of `a` which have a value equal to the values of `b` offset by some number `n`?

I would think something like this would work but I get a `elementwise == comparison failed` warning and an empty array as a result:

```
np.where(a == b + n)
```

Here's a for loop that accomplishes what I'm trying to do:

```
for val in b:
    print(np.where(a == val + n))
```

It outputs:

```
(array([3]),)
(array([4]),)
(array([6]),)
(array([7]),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b = np.array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9])
>>> n = 3
>>> np.where((a == b[:, np.newaxis] + n).any(axis=0))
(array([3, 4, 6, 7]),)
```

The idea is to broadcast `a` across `b` since you want to check against every possible value of `b`. At the end of the day, it's an `O(len(a) * len(b))` operation, so you'll need to create a 2D array of size `len(a) * len(b)` to vectorize.

Broadcasting is achieved by inserting another axis into `b` so that it is a column vector:

```py
>>> b
array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [3],
       [4],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

so that now, a comparison will return a 2D array:

```py
>>> a == b[:, np.newaxis] + n
array([[False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

The indices `i, j` where there is a `True` value mean that `b[i] == a[j]`. Since we only care about the indices of `a` that match any value in `b`, we just look for *any* true value along the columns:

```py
>>> (a == b[:, np.newaxis] + n).any(axis=0)
array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False])
```

Finally, all that is needed is to get the indices corresponding to the `True` values here:

```py
>>> np.where((a == b[:, np.newaxis] + n).any(axis=0))
(array([3, 4, 6, 7]),)
```

---

Your example input has sorted arrays, which means you can actually do a linear operation in `O(len(a) + len(b))`, but you won't be able to vectorize it in general. Basically you could have an index into each array, increment one at a time in `b` and keep incrementing in `a` until you hit the next value. Of course this would be less efficient in general with numpy arrays than my above solution for 'typical' (i.e. not massive) arrays.